# How to restart PM2 process automatically when it crashs?

Tags: linux, pm2

PM2 can keep Node service alive, but how to ensure itself alive(maybe crashes unexpectedly)? I want to know both the system way and tools to do it.

(I mean in Linux)

Answer (score 1):

You have to describe pm2 as service for systemd and specify restart/disable instructions.
[This](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files) shoud be helpfull.